# Docker have the same file in multiple layers

Tags: docker, caching

It is a common practice to copy `package.json` or `requirements.txt` in advance to leverage the Docker cache and prevent installing dependencies each time the sources change:

```
# Install python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy sources and models
COPY . .
```

The COPY command should only copy changed files. However, if COPY occurs multiple times in one Dockerfile, the same file suddenly appears in multiple layers. So the final image is larger. I am using the same technique to pre-COPY a 7GB file. Sadly, my final image has 14GB because this file is present in two layers.

To simulate the problem, create a text file `a.txt` with some dummy content. Use `.dockerignore` to not copy `Dockerfile` and `.dockerignore`. Then use the following Dockerfile to build an image:

```
FROM alpine
COPY a.txt .
COPY . .
CMD ["ls", "-la"]
```

After building, check the size with `docker image history image-name`. The file a.txt (4B) is wrongly included in 2 layers.

```
IMAGE          CREATED         CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
9fd840bc8435   5 seconds ago   CMD ["ls" "-la"]                                0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      5 seconds ago   COPY . . # buildkit                             4B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 minutes ago   COPY a.txt . # buildkit                         4B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      7 weeks ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:9233f6f2237d79659…   5.59MB
```

Comment: Since `COPY` doesn't have any exclusions or negative matches, you need to list out the files or directories you want to copy, if it's not "everything".  (You might consider whether you need to include a 7 GB file in an image at all; I've run into practical problems in the past with single image layers above about 1 GB.)

Comment: It is a language model. The image will be used to deploy it in a cloud, so the language model must be included in the image to make the deployment easy. And I don't want to copy the model with every change in the Python sources. That is the reason why I copy the model first, then the rest (everything).

Comment: When I've dealt with a similar problem in the past, the practical solution I landed on was to not include the large data set in the image at all (keeping the image size down to something Docker can handle) but instead bind-mounting it into the container at runtime.  That's definitely an exception to normal Docker practice, though.

Comment: Yes, that is the best option when running locally or on a server where you can access the file system. However, not suitable for a cloud-based deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern where you copy a file like package.json first and then later copy all files is done to support a development process where you build often and want to minimise the time that process takes.

If you have other concerns that you want to prioritize, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to do that.

For instance, if you build often, your Dockerfile could look like this

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY a.txt .
COPY . .
CMD ["ls", "-la"]
```

If you want to minimise final image size, you can create another Dockerfile that copies everything from that image in a single operation like this

```
FROM my-build-image as build
FROM alpine as final
COPY --from=build /app /app
```

Having a single Dockerfile that is both quick when you build a lot and also minimizes space use is not doable, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation! :) My goal is not to COPY and push the large static file (a ML model) every time I change something in sources. If I understand it correctly, I should have the large file in a separate folder to avoid copying it with `COPY . .`. And maybe also in a separate image. Am I right?

Comment: When you do `COPY . .` you copy the whole build context and there's no way to access anything outside the build context. So that would always include the large file. You'd have to split it up somehow, so you can copy the rest without copying the large file. Maybe move all files except the large one to a directory called `the_rest` and then do `COPY the_rest/* .`

Comment: Yes, it helped! Moving everything to a separate folder `src` helped. Now, the `COPY src .` command copies only the sources and the big file is correctly cached in the previous layer `COPY big-file .` :) Thanks!